# "makes everyone feel" or "make everyone feels"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, bare-infinitives, third-person-singular

https://www.lingq.com/lesson/lesson-26-giving-a-speech-431421/

"Talking about milestones and achievements ***makes everyone feel*** involved and positive, and it also shows how hard you worked for the company without making you seem arrogant."

Why at the above context there is "makes everyone feel" and there is not "make everyone feels"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main verb is *makes*. It is third person singular, so it takes the appropriate ending *-s*.

*Make* in this sense has the structure *make [noun phrase] [bare infinitive] [possible arguments of the infinitive verb]*. There is no reason why it has to have this shape, it just does (*hear* has the same structure eg "I heard him go out"; but *want* has a different structure, requiring the "to" infinitive, eg "I want him to leave").

So *feel* is in the bare infinitive, i.e. the base form *feel*.

Answer (score 2):

It would be **feel**. This pattern with **make** will always be complemented by the bare infinitive.

Make it *go*

Make it *seem*

Make them *feel*

Make the engine *stall*